# Convert bash script to powershell

Tags: bash, powershell

I need to convert what looks like a pretty simple bash script to powershell but I'm pretty new to both.

The original script is:

```
alias cptimestamp="date +"%Y%m%d%H%M" | clip"
```

I've gotten this far but I'm not sure:

```
function cptimestamp {
 cptimestamp="date +"%Y%m%d%H%M" | clip"
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out what the 'clip' part does.

Comment: `| clip` copies the output to the Windows clipboard (with a trailing newline). The bigger question is: What are you trying to do? Get the current date and time (in some particular format) and copy it to the clipboard?

Comment: Can you describe what your original script does or is intended to do?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart yes, and then it's being appended to a file name so that the dates are all in the same format

Comment: Why do you need to copy it to the clipboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent of `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M"` in PowerShell would be:

```
Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M"
```

So your function should probably look like this:

```
function cptimestamp {
  Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M" |Set-ClipBoard
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of your PowerShell function is to copy the current date and time to the Windows clipboard, I would probably use this:

```
function cptimestamp {
  [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText((Get-Date -Uformat "%Y%m%d%H%M"))
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
function cptimestamp {
  [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText((Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddhhmmss"))
}
```